# Is there a way to get datasvcutil to generate code with a custom namespace?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, datasvcutil

When you generate client Service code using the Visual Studio UI you can select a namespace that you want to use.

However if you are generating client code using **datasvcutil** I can't seem to find a similar option.  (It creates the namespace based on the service it is accessing.)

Is there a way to ask datasvcutil to generate the client code with a different namespace?

**For example:**

If you run this from the Visual Studio Command Line Prompt:

> datasvcutil /out:"C:\temp\datasvc.cs" /uri:https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom /language:CSharp /version:2.0

Then the resulting file has a namespace of MetaModel.

**However**, if I do the same thing from the UI:

[image: Add Service Reference Dialog]

Then the resulting file has the namespace *MyProject.StackOverflow*.

Is there a way I can mimic what the UI does from the command line?

Answer (score -1):

Write powershell script with .net reflection methods to get namespace to generate appropriate command line and run datasvcutil with generated parameters

Comment: I have moved on from this issue, but this answer it too vague for me to accept it.